# Access SQL return all combinations of any 4 numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, math

I am try to get my query to have a criteria to return all of the possible combinations I can make with the following 2, 1, 2, and 3.

I attempted the following WHERE clause:

```
    WHERE (((dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%2%" And
    (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%1%" And
    (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%2%" And
    (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%3%"));
```

This works for numbers up to 4 digits if all the numbers are unique in my alike statements, the problem I am running into is the 2 appearing twice returns values like 1237 which is unacceptable and 1232 which is acceptable. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you need. Are you trying to return a list of all the EmployeeIDs that have 2123 somewhere in it?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good use of SQL to me.  Better to formulate that query differently (e.g. WHERE EmployeeID IN (.....))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want with logic like this:

```
WHERE (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%2%2%" And
      (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%1%" And
      (dbo_tblHR_Employees.EmployeeID) ALike "%3%");
```